# How to load large csv file into on prem sql database using power automate

Tags: power-automate

Does anyone know how to load a large csv file into an on prem sql database using power automate?

I am using an apply to each to parse the csv file & break it into individual sql inserts using sql insert row, but this takes way too long for 1200 records. it takes 19 minutes. I am looking for another way to do this faster or in bulk.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and use ADF. IMO and most others, you’re not using the most appropriate tool for the job. If you don’t want to change then can you update your question with some sample data?